# when move my camera, it doesn't orbit like it should do

Tags: 3d-view, camera

when  move my camera, it doesn't orbit like it should do. Instead it moves like you move your head. Also, when i do ctrl alt numpad 0 (cmd alt numpad 0 on mac i assume) it doesn't snap the camera to the current view if i'm in view mode or camera mode.

Comment: Please one question at the time. For different questions use different posts.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the view around an object follow these steps:

- ALT + MIDDLE CLICK on the object you want to rotate your view around
- MIDDLE CLICK (keep pressed) and move the mouse to rotate the view

Please note that the viewport view is not the camera view (but you probably already know it)

Comment: i think my local camera was set on camera instead of the mesh i want to use